# Typesetting exclamation+question+ellipsis (!.. ?.. ?!. !?.)

Tags: kerning

All of us know that we should use `\dots` instead of `...` (three single dots).

But how can I typeset correctly the combination of an exclamation mark with an ellipsis (`!..`) or a question mark with an ellipsis (`?..`), or both marks with a dot (`?!.`, `!?.`)?

I want to have dots on equal distances — same as in `\dots`.

Of course, I can guess the kerning, but this solution will be font-dependent :-(

Comment: I'd suggest that the question / exclamation mark and the ellipsis are independent and you should therefore use `?\dots`, rather than overwriting the dots.  However the spacing may not be what you'd like, it may come out rather like ". ...".

Comment: @ChrisH That doesn't work: you cannot redefine the country-wide standards in typography and use four dots instead of three (?...)

Comment: @pantlmn -- i'm not familiar with the standards you're referring to.  in what country are they used?  (your profile doesn't identify that.)  in the u;s., it *is* sometimes considered appropriate to use `\dots` plus a period to show definitively that this is the end of a sentence.  and i've never seen either an exclamation or question mark with "attached" dots; a full three-dot sequence following a space after such punctuation indicates an omission from discourse in a quote.  (i agree with following local standards, but provenance is important.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Russian typografic rules allow usage of "!.." and "?.." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis#In_Russian)

Comment: I didn’t know that about Russian typography.  Thanks!

Comment: Deleted my answer as not answering your question, then.  (If anyone cares, the command for an interrobang is `\textinterrobang`.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure what these character combination should mean. Anyway, here they are; still font dependent, I'm afraid, because the shape of `?` gets in the way, so I provide a “parameter” for it. Uncomment one of the font packages to see the effect with a different font; for these two a change in `\centqmkern` doesn't seem necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{erewhon}
%\usepackage{newtxtext}

\newcommand{\centqm}{\makebox[\fontcharwd\font`.]{?}}
\newcommand{\centqmkern}{\kern.2\fontcharwd\font`?}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\edots}{%
  !\kern\fontdimen3\font
  .\kern\fontdimen3\font
  .\kern\fontdimen3\font
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\qdots}{%
  \centqmkern
  \centqm\kern\fontdimen3\font
  .\kern\fontdimen3\font
  .\kern\fontdimen3\font
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\qedots}{%
  \centqmkern
  \centqm\kern\fontdimen3\font
  !\kern\fontdimen3\font
  .\kern\fontdimen3\font
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\eqdots}{%
  !\kern\fontdimen3\font
  \centqm\kern\fontdimen3\font
  .\kern\fontdimen3\font
}

\begin{document}

Text\dots

Text\edots

Text\eqdots

Text\qdots

Text\qedots

Text?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Worked perfect. The meaning of the signs is rather closely shown by `jlv` in the dialogue. Ellipsis shows hesitation and that the phrase is kind of unfinished.

Comment: @pantlmn Something I'd never use. `;-)`

Comment: Tested your solution a bit more: actually, you don't need `\kern\fontdimen3\font` after the last dot. Test example is : `«Really\qedots» — said John.`

Comment: @pantlmn That's what the standard `\dots` (more precisely `\textellipsis`) does.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the macro `\eli` followed by three symbols. For example `Text\eli?..` The advantage is that you needn't to specify explicit space after this. The name `\eli` means ellipsis.

```
\def\eli#1#2#3{%
   \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
   \setbox2=\hbox{.}%
   \kern.5\wd0
   \cbox{#1}\kern1.6\wd2\cbox{#2}\kern1.6\wd2\cbox{#3}%
   \kern\wd2
}
\def\cbox#1{\hbox to0pt{\hss#1\hss}}

Text\eli... Text\eli?.. Text\eli!.. Text\eli?!.

\bye
```

Result:

[image: eli]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there are commands for the symbols you mention, but there is a way to make it look like what you want, with `\rlap` (see [here](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb22-4/tb72perlS.pdf) for more details). Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\begin{document}

\noindent
Hello\rlap{\dots}!\\
Yes\rlap{\dots}?\\
May I come in\rlap{\hspace{1pt}\dots}?\\
Why\rlap{\dots}?!\\
Why not\rlap{\hspace{1pt}\dots}?\hspace{1pt}!\\
Because\rlap{\dots}!?\\
Never\rlap{\dots}!\hspace{1pt}?

\end{document}
```

And here's the resulting image:

[image]

As you can see, there are some problems, since the question mark does not have quite the same spacing as the exclamation point, but a little adjustment makes it work nicely.

Comment: There is no use or `\rlap{\dots}` if you use manual kerning. It's much better to have uneven spaces between punctuation signs than to get extra dots or strange-shaped dots.